# Attach EBS Volume to EKS Cluster nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Usually, the attachment of EBS volumes can be accomplished using:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/volume_attachment.html


Unfortunately, in my case I do define nodes using EKS Cluster & worker_groups [DEFINITION](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/12.0.0):

```
module "my-cluster" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  cluster_name    = "my-cluster"
  cluster_version = "1.16"
  subnets         = ["subnet-abcde012", "subnet-bcde012a", "subnet-fghi345a"]
  vpc_id          = "vpc-1234556abcdef"

  worker_groups = [
    {
      instance_type = "m4.large"
      asg_max_size  = 5
    }
  ]
}
```

It makes me unable to get IDs of these EC2 instances.

What is the best way of mounting EBS in such a situation?
How can I get IDs of nodes created using EKS Cluster?

Comment: Are you just wanting to attach an extra empty EBS volume to the worker nodes? Or are you trying to attach an EBS volume that has persistent data on it? If you need persistent data is this for the node itself or for pods running on the cluster?

Comment: I need a persistent data for pods running on the cluster.
The case is that I have Elasticsearch running as a POD. The process of indexing takes a couple of hours. I want to create a snapshot of the Elasticsearch EBS and reuse it whenever new clusters will be created, so that I will not have to wait another hours till Elasticsearch will be ready to use

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a persistent volume claim for that if it's for a pod? Attaching the EBS volume directly to the instance seems like the wrong move here.

Comment: This is definitely a use case for a PVC, especially given that people regularly use it for this functionality with ES inside k8s.

Comment: tbh, altough it "can" be done (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/), pv/pvc on eks is amazingly in-intuitive and complex. having to install a specific drive sounds insane. if im not wrong, op asks about how do you specify  that a **given**ebs get attached to a **given** eks instance. this specific  info is nowhere to be found